# typeahead + BloodHound suggestion engine not displaying results from Json and

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, typeahead, bloodhound

So, i am using bloodhound suggestion engine and typeahead for a searchBar/suggestionBar that should display the "providerName" (this info is taked from some text inputs) from a **JSON** that is in a **PHP mongo server.**
The big problem here is that i think it doesn't like the json i am uploading because i have tried with other jsons like this one http://revox.io/json/countries-list.json
and it works fine. but with mine it doesn't.
The pecularity in here is that when i press "o" in the search bar it displays the json file itself (not talking about the information of it but the JSON FILE itself).
At the end i just want the search bar to display the "providerName" the rest is not important for this part

** js script i am using to call the JSON from the php server (it works
 fine with the countries JSON)**

```
var providers = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('providerName'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: 'http://localhost:63342/insurancev2/api/apps/inventory/requestProviders.php'
    });
    // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
    $scope.countriesOptions = {
        highlight: true
    };
    $scope.providerData = {
        name: 'providersName',
        source: providers
    }
    $scope.provider = null;




}])
```

the JSON i am uploading

`{
    "593f280575938b4e020041ff": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "593f280575938b4e020041ff"
        },
        "providerName": "jose",
        "providerPhone": "898799",
        "providerEmail": "ajfjafjj",
        "providerContact": "enriquie",
        "providerBank": "980988098"
    },
    "59400bfe75938b4a0200420e": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "59400bfe75938b4a0200420e"
        },
        "providerName": "Cafe Duran",
        "providerPhone": "888-908",
        "providerEmail": "durancafe@outlook.com",
        "providerContact": "KC",
        "providerBank": "89876798"
    },
    "59413d7c75938bea0a00428e": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "59413d7c75938bea0a00428e"
        },
        "providerName": "cafecito",
        "providerPhone": "1-581-88",
        "providerEmail": "jppiipi",
        "providerContact": "jose",
        "providerBank": "78909876"
    },
    "59413fff75938bea0a0042a1": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "59413fff75938bea0a0042a1"
        },
        "providerName": "josesillo",
        "providerPhone": "41515",
        "providerEmail": "josesgf",
        "providerContact": "999899",
        "providerBank": "-98888"
    },
    "594140bf75938bea0a0042a8": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "594140bf75938bea0a0042a8"
        },
        "providerName": "114",
        "providerPhone": "44141",
        "providerEmail": "41414",
        "providerContact": "11414",
        "providerBank": "1414"
    },
    "594140f575938bea0a0042af": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "594140f575938bea0a0042af"
        },
        "providerName": "a13r41",
        "providerPhone": "1414",
        "providerEmail": "1414",
        "providerContact": "1414",
        "providerBank": "4141"
    },
    "5941444175938bea0a0042c8": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "5941444175938bea0a0042c8"
        },
        "0": "calcuta",
        "1": "8987899",
        "2": "calcuta@outlook.cokj",
        "3": "casaornage",
        "4": "9876546789"
    },
    "5941458975938bea0a0042e7": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "5941458975938bea0a0042e7"
        },
        "providerName": "saquela",
        "providerPhone": "cagafe",
        "providerEmail": "jose",
        "providerContact": "fqf",
        "providerBank": "qsfqw"
    }
}`

Comment: It would be great if you could boil down the code to **just** contain **everything needed** to **reproduce** the problem, not more.

Comment: oh ok, let me  edit the post

Answer (score 0):

Consider add the `display` option like bellow. And provide a `name` is optional.

```js
$scope.providerData = {
    display: 'providersName',
    source: providers
}
```